# How do I get my previous request of information off of "on hold"?

Tags: discussion

I guess i worded my first question on my profile wrong or was unclear about it, but I recently edited it and added comments to verify. Still on hold, can anyone inform me please.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you make sure that your [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1116036/how-can-i-upgrade-my-computers-performance) contains **all** the information that anyone could need to give you an answer.  Currently a lot of the information is contained in badly formatted comments.

Secondly, you wait.  Your question has been put into a queue for [review](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/567614) where community members will see if you have brought your question into line with our recommendations.

If your question still doesn't get reopened then editing it to give us everything you've tried in the mean time will help.

Some resources that might help:

- How to [format your questions](https://superuser.com/editing-help)
- How to [ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)
- What [questions are on-topic here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4):

For everyone else's convenience, here's the question you previously posted: https://superuser.com/q/1116036/380318

When you add new information, you should add it to the body of the post, using the "edit" link below it, rather than posting comments. More importantly, you should read the help center, especially the pages on [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) You'll find that your question is currently too broad for this site, and may be interpreted by some as a hardware recommendation, which is off-topic because such recommendations tend to go out of date quickly.

If you edit the question to fix those issues, it will be automatically pushed into the Reopen Votes queue. If the reviewers agree that you have repaired your question, they will reopen it to allow new answers. This process may take a few hours or a day, so be patient.

If your question can't be turned into something fit to our Q&A format, you might try asking somewhere else. For example, we have chat rooms, which you can post in once you gain some reputation.